# Building Chakra-Core (C++) statically on Windows

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio, chakra, chakracore

I want to build Chakra-Core statically. Currently, in Visual Studio I have to link with `ChakraCore.lib` at compile time and with `ChakraCore.dll` at runtime. I tried building the solution through Visual Studio by changing the configuration type from `DLL` to `LIB (static library)` but that caused errors. So I just want to be linking with Chakra-Core at compile time and do not want to distribute its `DLL` with my executable.

If I build the project with LIB (Static Library) configuration, I get this error:

`ChakraCore-master\Build\VcBuild\obj\x64_release\ChakraCore\ChakraCore.def : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x18B5 2>Done building project "ChakraCore.vcxproj" -- FAILED. ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 25 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========`

Comment: Presumably you've read the [documentation] (https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/wiki/Building-ChakraCore)? We'll need to see the error messages if you want help with your problem

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62643091/edit) this into your question

Comment: I am sorry, I am kind of new to this Stackoverflow thing :P